# ViewPatterns and multiple calls in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, language-extension

I read this:

http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns

I like the idea, want to use the extension. I however would like to make sure as to one thing: whether the view function is evaluated once for a single matching.

So let's say we have:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
...

f (view -> Nothing) = ...
f (view -> Just x) = ...

view :: a -> Maybe b
```

Now let's say I invoke `f a`. Is `view` invoked twice or just once for the given argument `a`?

**EDIT**:

I tried to find out whether this is the case and wrote the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import System.IO.Unsafe

blah (ble -> Nothing) = 123
blah (ble -> Just x) = x

ble x = unsafePerformIO $ do
    putStrLn $ "Inside ble: " ++ show x
    return x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ "Main: " ++ show (blah $ Just 234)
```

Output using GHC:

```
Inside ble: Just 234
Inside ble: Just 234
Main: 234
```

Output using GHC (with optimization)

```
Inside ble: Just 234
Main: 234
```

Output using GHCi:

```
Main: Inside ble: Just 234
Inside ble: Just 234
234
```

Comment: GHC has a special hack to avoid recomputation of identical view expressions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just once:

> Efficiency: When the same view function is applied in
> multiple branches of a function definition or a case expression (e.g.,
> in `size` above), GHC makes an attempt to collect these
> applications into a single nested case expression, so that the view
> function is only applied once.  Pattern compilation in GHC follows the
> matrix algorithm described in Chapter 4 of [The
> Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/Papers/slpj-book-1987/).  When the
> top rows of the first column of a matrix are all view patterns with the
> "same" expression, these patterns are transformed into a single nested
> case.  This includes, for example, adjacent view patterns that line up
> in a tuple, as in
>
> ```
> f ((view -> A, p1), p2) = e1
> f ((view -> B, p3), p4) = e2
> ```
>
> The current notion of when two view pattern expressions are "the
> same" is very restricted: it is not even full syntactic equality.
> However, it does include variables, literals, applications, and tuples;
> e.g., two instances of `view ("hi", "there")` will be
> collected.  However, the current implementation does not compare up to
> alpha-equivalence, so two instances of `(x, view x -> y)` will not be coalesced.
>
> — [The GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns)

As for your snippet, the problem is that you're not compiling with optimisation; with both `ghc -O` and `ghc -O2`, the line is only printed once. That's always the first thing to check when you have performance-related problems when using GHC :)

(By the way, [Debug.Trace](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html) lets you check these kinds of things without having to write manual `unsafePerformIO` hacks.)

Comment: Is it possible that GHC is inserting additional spare evaluations because of performUnsafeIO? Don't worry, I used it just to test the feature.

Comment: Yes, that's me being a newbie still. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For some reason I feel like using `Debug.Trace` is just fine, but `unsafePerformIO` is generally horrific, even though `Debug.Trace` just uses `unsafePerformIO` under the hood.

Comment: @DanBurton Yes, you're right, I should have used `Debug.Trace` for that, it would be clearer what I wanted to do.